# Unable to implement dark mode in html website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am in the midst of building my HTML webpage and i wanted to implement a dark mode for my webpage. I've viewed quite alot of examples on the web and i tried to implement 1 from the web. However, i tried to link the HTML webpage and JavaScript together, but it seemed that my webpage still cannot change to dark mode. Is there something wrong with my code?

```js
    let toggle = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

document.body.setAttribute("dark-theme", false);

toggle.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        document.body.setAttribute("dark-theme", true);
    } else {
        document.body.setAttribute("dark-theme", false);
    }
});
```

```css
  
 body[dark-theme="true"] p {
  color: #000;
}

body[dark-theme="false"] p {
  color: #fff;
}

/* CSS Feature For Slider Button */
.theme-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 34px;
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
}

.theme-switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  background-color: #ccc;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.slider:before {
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: 4px;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.4s;
  width: 26px;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #66bb6a;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <!-- External CSS stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />

    <!-- Mandatory bootstrap tags -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Title and Favicon -->
    <title>Jibaboom! ∙ DataViewer</title>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="./favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="./favicons/site.webmanifest">

    <!-- Slider Script Src -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <!-- NavBar Experiment Feature-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-transparent bg-transparent">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="favicons/favicon.ico" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
                Jibaboom
            </a>

            <label class="theme-switch" for="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
                <div class="slider round"></div>
            </label>
        </nav>

        <!-- Data Viewer Table -->
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered my-5">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Doe</td>
                    <td>john@example.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mary</td>
                    <td>Moe</td>
                    <td>mary@example.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>July</td>
                    <td>Dooley</td>
                    <td>july@example.com</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <!-- Source For JS Responsive Script -->
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

<footer class="site-footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <p class="copyright-text">Copyright &copy; 2020 All Rights Reserved by Jibaboom
                    <a href="#">skrtttt</a>.
                </p>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: What is this code `document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");` supposed to do here?

Comment: It seems you are setting the attribute `data-theme` but you are not setting the `class` for said theme. So the data is updated but the HTML continues to use the same CSS for styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion:

```
let toggle = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

document.body.setAttribute('dark-theme', false);
document.querySelector('footer').setAttribute('dark-theme', false);

toggle.addEventListener('change', e => {

    if(e.target.checked) {

        document.body.setAttribute('dark-theme', true);
        document.querySelector('footer').setAttribute('dark-theme', true);

    } else {

        document.body.setAttribute('dark-theme', false);
        document.querySelector('footer').setAttribute('dark-theme', false);

    }

});
```

When the checkbox is checked, the body element on your page gets an attribute ('dark-theme') as a true or false value. you can use this in plain css to then apply dark or light styles throughout the page. A boilerplate example could be:

```
body[dark-theme=true] p { color: #fff; }

body[dark-theme=false] p { color: #000; }

footer[dark-theme=true] p { color: #fff; }

footer[dark-theme=false] p { color: #000; }
```

Although this is a different approach to what you've tried to do in your answer, I personally find this to be much simpler. Let me know if you find any problems with this solution so I can assist you further.

Comment: Hi @syedmh. Sorry for the late reply! Gotta go to the hospital for screening you know... But anyways, thanks for the help! I've tried to plug in yur solution into my model and it worked but when i add in a footer and some elements, it seems that my footer had been eaten up and the webpage doesn't render and dark mode anymore. I've updated the codes at the top already.Could you please help me out with it? Thank You!

Comment: Hey, hope you're doing well. im glad it helped. If your footer is outside the body tag of your document, it won't be affected by the body attribute [dark-theme]. let me know if the footer is outside the body tags so i can adjust my answer to add the attribute to your footer too

Comment: Yep, i checked. My footer is an element itself, outside the body tags.

Comment: is your script being called above or below the footer?

Comment: err, its above the footer. in fact it's concatenated in the body tag at the bottom.

Comment: is there any way you can include the script in your footer as opposed to your body tags?

Comment: i tried including the script in the footer and removed from the body tags, but the problem is still there.

Comment: okay, now that the script is in the footer tags, I'll update my answer to add the attribute to your footer as well.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector(
  '.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]'
);
// Had to remove local storage for security. Make sure to uncomment in your code.
// const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");

// if (currentTheme) {
//   document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", currentTheme);

//  if (currentTheme === "dark") {
//    toggleSwitch.checked = true;
//  }
// }

function switchTheme(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
    // localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
  } else {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "light");
    // localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
  }
}

toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme)
```

```css
[data-theme="dark"] {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.theme-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 34px;
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
}

.theme-switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  background-color: #ccc;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: 4px;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .4s;
  width: 26px;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #66bb6a;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-transparent bg-transparent">
      <label class="theme-switch" for="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
                <div class="slider round"></div>
        </label>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

You need to add an event listener to your checkbox so your javascript should look like:

```js
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector(
  '.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]'
);
const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");

if (currentTheme) {
  document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", currentTheme);

  if (currentTheme === "dark") {
    toggleSwitch.checked = true;
  }
}

function switchTheme(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
  } else {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "light");
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
  }
}

toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme)
```

You also need to change your `.dark-mode` CSS selector to `[data-theme="dark"]`

Comment: yes, this might be part of it, but this alone will not fix the issue